# Как сделать антифлуд в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть что-то типо кликера.
Проблема в том, что бот отвечает юзеру после каждого клика, идёт в бд и записывает и из-за этого бот тупит. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы если юзер флудит одним и тем же сообщением, то бот ждёт, пока он перестанет флудить (например, если юзер не пишет 2-3 секунды), посчитает сколько раз юзер нажал на кнопку за это время и затем ответил ему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте middleware для того, чтобы перед каждым попаданием апдейта в хендлеры проходила проверка на время предыдущего апдейта от конкретного юзера.

```
# aiogram 3.x

import datetime
from typing import Callable, Awaitable, Dict, Any

from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import TelegramObject, Message, CallbackQuery

class AntiFloodMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    time_updates: dict[int, datetime.datetime] = {}
    timedelta_limiter: datetime.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3)

    async def __call__(
            self,
            handler: Callable[[TelegramObject, Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
            event: TelegramObject,
            data: Dict[str, Any],
    ) -> Any:
        if isinstance(event, (Message, CallbackQuery)):
            user_id = event.from_user.id
            if user_id in self.time_updates.keys():
                if (datetime.datetime.now() - self.time_updates[user_id]) > self.timedelta_limiter:
                    self.time_updates[user_id] = datetime.datetime.now()
                    return await handler(event, data)
            else:
                self.time_updates[user_id] = datetime.datetime.now()
                return await handler(event, data)
```